# Can any one explain this SQL Query?

Tags: sql

Today, my boss told the below SQL query and went out without explaining it. Its working good.
But i want to know the way how it works.

```
SELECT NAME 
  FROM PERMISSIONTOKENS 
 WHERE ID IN (SELECT TOKENID 
                FROM ROLETOKENASSOCIATION 
               WHERE ROLEID = '1');
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two queries here.

The inner query:

```
SELECT TOKENID FROM ROLETOKENASSOCIATION WHERE ROLEID = '1'
```

Will get all of the `TOKENID`s from `ROLETOKENASSOCIATION` that have a `ROLEID` of `1`.

The outer query:

```
SELECT NAME FROM PERMISSIONTOKENS WHERE ID IN(...)
```

This will get all of the names from `PERMISSIONTOKENS` that have an ID that was in the result set of the inner query.

You might be able to re-write this with joins instead of using `IN`, if you don't like the syntax of `IN`.

Answer (score 5):

This is a subquery.

Basically the inner `SELECT` retrieves the token ID's, which are then fed back into the outer `SELECT` query. You could also achieve the same using an `INNER JOIN`:

```
    SELECT name 
      FROM PERMISSIONTOKENS pt
INNER JOIN ROLETOKENASSOCIATION rta ON rta.TOKENID = pt.ID
     WHERE rta.ROLEID = '1';
```

Comment: Thanks. +1 to you for the detailed explanation of everything else :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TOKENID FROM ROLETOKENASSOCIATION WHERE ROLEID = '1'
```

It selects all TOKENID where the ROLEID is 1. This is a *subquery* of the query:

```
SELECT NAME FROM PERMISSIONTOKENS WHERE ID IN (...)
```

The (...) is the set of all TOKENID selected. Therefore, the whole query will select the NAMEs, where the ID is one of those TOKENID with ROLEID = 1.

Answer (score 0):

It select field NAME from rows for which ID is in this set of values : all the TOKENID from the row of the table ROLETOKENASSOCIATION for which ROLEID = '1'.

Answer (score 0):

For each TokenID in the RoleTokenAssociation table, where the RoleId is "1", it will return the name of that token from PermissionTokens table.